# Firestore: how to set up GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following the [official Google docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) to to access firestore from an android app (Xamarin). Every time I try to access firestore, I get the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials/ for more information.

The exception is pretty clear. I have to set up the environment variable. So I ran the following PowerShell command:

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:/Foo/Bar/google-services.json"
```

That didn't work. Maybe the json file has to be on the Android device. I set the json file to be "Embedded Content" and inserted the following line into the app, before accessing the database (using System, using System.IO):

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"../../Firestore/google-services.json"));
```

That changed the exception to "the path isn't valid". How do I get the path to the json file? This is my hierarchy:

[image: Xamarin Project solution explorer hierarchy showing the location of google-services.json]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're method not working :

According to [Getting Started with Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable), you can set it by using command prompt

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[PATH]
```

You can try this method

<kbd>Start</kbd> -> <kbd>This Pc</kbd> (Right Click on My Computer) -> <kbd>Properties</kbd> -> On Left panel you will find

<kbd>Advance System Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Enviorment Variable</kbd>

Then **Add User Variable For #UserName#** And **System Variables** :

Click On <kbd>New</kbd> It will provide you popup and provide the

> **Variable Name :** GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

> **Variable Value :** Just provide the path of Json File. It will set automatically for appilcation default.

You can Select file with given button :

[image]

Even on Github Issue [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) explained in his [answer](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-dotnet/issues/175#issuecomment-299463984)

Comment: I added the variable and got System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error reading credential file from location (my path here)'. I supplied an absolute path. Should I use a relative path? And relative to what?

Comment: You can copy path from the File Setting-> Properties-> Security

Comment: I'm using this path: "D:\\Android\AndroidSandbox\AndroidSandbox\Firestore\google-services.json" and still getting the System.InvalidOperationException.

Comment: @Bip901 i posted image to help you understand, with that button you can select file and path will be saved

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists. I do appreciate the help though - I'll accept this answer if no other answers are posted after a while.